# How to make condition check data sent on time or not in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have tried to make it but it's not working.

My code:

```html
@if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($tugas->created_at)->toDateString() < Carbon\Carbon::parse($sub->deadline)->toDateString())
    @if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($tugas->created_at)->toTimeString() < Carbon\Carbon::parse($sub->deadline)->toTimeString())
        <td class="table-success">On time</td>
    @else
        <td class="table-danger">late</td>
    @endif
@else
    <td class="table-danger">late</td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Date instance (and so Carbon instance too) can be compared without being converted into strings:

```php
@if (new \Carbon\Carbon($tugas->created_at) < new \Carbon\Carbon($sub->deadline))
    <td class="table-success">On time</td>
@else
    <td class="table-danger">late</td>
@endif
```

Then ensure all those instances are in the same timezone to avoid surprises.

Comment: "not working" is not a proper behavior description, please edit the question with static values (exact content of $tugas->created_at and $sub->deadline) and describe exactly what you get and expect.

Comment: For instance, I don't get why you have 2 identical conditions nested

Comment: i have fix it but thaks for the response

Answer (score 0):

By default, `created_at` should already been cast to [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) so I recommend doing the same with `deadline`.

```
class Sub extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'deadline' => 'datetime'
    ];
}
```

You can't really compare date strings. They have to be Carbon objects. Carbon offers methods for comparison:

```
@if ($tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->deadline))
    @if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($tugas->created_at)->toTimeString() < Carbon\Carbon::parse($sub->deadline)->toTimeString())
        <td class="table-success">On time</td>
    @else
        <td class="table-danger">late</td>
    @endif
@else
    <td class="table-danger">late</td>
@endif
```

I guess, the second comparison is now somewhat obsolete so it can be shortened to this:

```
@if ($tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->deadline))
    <td class="table-success">On time</td>
@else
    <td class="table-danger">late</td>
@endif
```

Comment: do you have another way?

Comment: Is there a reason, you do two comparisons? One for the time and one for the date? If not, you can remove line 2 and 4 to 6.

Comment: I have made it as you have made by using one comparisons because the two data types of the variable are datetime but it still doesn't work
thx btw

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Can you add the expected vs the actual result to your question? What happens if you `dd($tugas->created_at, $sub->deadline, $tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->deadline));`?

Comment: Sorry guys, it turns out that I made a mistake when applying your code and now the code is running well. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Carbon::now()->lessThan(Carbon::now()->subMinute()) // false
```

This is date comparison

Comment: Why would you do `subMinute()`?